# How to extract Attribute and variation from Array woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to show attribute type and variation on my custom made minicart in woocommerce. I use `WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $item ];` to get cart item object. and using `wc_implode_text_attributes()` to extract value from **array** where `$variation_name` return name but not attribute.

Attribute =  color
variation = green , red , yellow

So I want output should be like

> color:green

but the current output is only showing

> green

```
$cart_item = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $item ];
if( $cart_item['data']->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
    $attributes = $cart_item['data']->get_attributes();
    $variation_name = wc_implode_text_attributes( $attributes );
    var_dump( $attributes);
}
```

The dump result is

> array(1) { ["color"]=> string(5) "green" }

So how Can I extract this dump like `color:green` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your codes with follows -

```
$cart_item = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $item ];
if( $cart_item['data']->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
    $attributes = $cart_item['data']->get_attributes();
    $variation_names = array();
    if( $attributes ){
        foreach ( $attributes as $key => $value) {
            $variation_names[] = $key .': '. $value;
        }
    }
    echo implode( '<br>', $variation_names );
}
```

Comment: Yes Thanks for the answer. But I already solved that array issue actually because of caching issue its not showing in front end.

Comment: @Firefog, you can contact me via my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6449385/itzmekhokan?tab=profile)

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart_item = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $item ];
    if( $cart_item['data']->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
    $attributes = $cart_item['data']->get_attributes();
    foreach($attributes as $attname => $variant) {
    $attribute_variation = $attname .  " : " . $variant;
    print($attribute_variation );
    }
}
```

Comment: please consider adding more explanation